# C++ Trapping system dialogs in a kiosk system

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, alerts

We have a kiosk system running on Win7 with application written using VS2010 C++.  As with kiosk systems, the system is locked down so that the user cannot access the windows system itself, but must do all work using our application.

Unfortunately, we have had one issue so far where a windows system-level dialog has popped up requiring a response.  It popped up behind the GUI of our application, so that the user didn't even know it was there, and since it was modal, it blocked further use of the system.

These dialog was the well-known "system needs to be restored" dialog.  Since this is a kiosk system, we are wanting to find a way to handle these types of situations in an automated fashion.

I have looked into setting a low level hook using SetWinEventHook() to capture EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT events.  The first problem of course is that I am not sure how to test this, since these events are not common.  The second problem is that I am not sure how to handle the information, since there could be a number of different system alert events that pop up modal windows, and so automating a response might get us into more trouble than we might foresee.

My real question here is, if you were in this exact situation, what would be your line of attack.  I am concerned I may be going about this the wrong way by trying to capture alerts and somehow automate a response to the resulting system alert window.

Any clues as to a useful direction here would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe that a *"system needs to be restored"* dialog is *"well-known"*. I, for one, don't know, what this dialog is. Anyway, I would tackle the problem by digging through group policies to see, if there is a way to disable system modal dialogs. If there isn't, I'd see if there is a way to file a Design Change Request with Microsoft to have them implement the functionality.

Comment: Windows updates are turned off on all of our machines.  I will start to look into system settings for turning off system modal dialogs, since that does seem to be the next obvious step.  I will comment further on what I find. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I did some more research into turning off dialogs, but I have the same misgivings about the system requiring something and our missing that.  We have only seen this once.  So I will bide my time until it happens again.  Thanks for your responses.  You have corroborated my theory that this is not something to play with lightly.  I'll update if I find more.